# How do you prove that a sequence diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, divergent-series

Specifically the sequence $\{(-2)^n\}$

Comment: The first step is to write down exactly what it means for this sequence to diverge, according to your definitions of convergence/divergence; can you do that?

Comment: It zigzags depending on $n$ odd or even, going to infinity in either direction (even $n$ to $+\infty$, odd to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there exists L such that $(-2)^n$ tends to L. Therefore we know that there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|(-2)^N-L|<0.5$ and $|(-2)^{N+1}-L|<0.5$ Using the triangle inequality we have:
$|(-2)^N-(-2)^{N+1}|<=|(-2)^N-L|+|(-2)^{N+1}-L|<1$ , thus $|(-2)^N||1--2|<1$ (a contradiction)

Comment: You’ve overlooked the possibility that the OP is supposed to consider a sequence convergent if it has a limit in the **extended** reals.

Answer (score 4):

You have one subsequence decreasing to $-\infty$ and another increasing exponentially to $\infty$.  No convergent sequence can have two distinct subsequential limits.